# Add link field to module output on Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have many field for my custom module.

And output:

```
    if($slides->rowCount() > 0 ){
        $output .= '<ul id="head_slider" class="clearfix">';
        foreach($slides as $sld):
            $nd = node_load($sld->nid);
            if(count($nd->field_simage) >  0){
                $img_url = image_style_url('img_960x378',$nd->field_simage['und'][0]['uri']);
            }
            $output .= '<li><img src="'.$img_url.'" alt="'.$sld->title.'" /></li>';
        endforeach;
        $output .= '</ul>';
    }


    return $output;
}
```

Content type has url field. It's name `field_surl` When users insert a link to this field, must wrap this link to my output.

I tried this but not working:

```
$output .= '<li><a href="'.$field_surl.'"><img src="'.$img_url.'" alt="'.$sld->title.'" /></a></li>';
```

That's output:

```
<a href='field_surl'>...</a>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Not working how? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you populating the variable $field_surl?

You need something like this:

```
$field_surl = isset($nd->field_surl['und'][0]['value']) ? $nd->field_surl['und'][0]['value'] : '';
```